# Canvas crop: resize image, mantain aspect ration and center? JsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i want to archive some simple image resize script before upload. I need to allow the user to upload an image and resize it before upload to server. Example i need an image 400x300 so if user uploads an 1080x680 i need to have same image but 400x300 centered.

```
.-------.-----.-------.      .------.
|///////|     |///////|      |//////|
|///////| 300 |///////|      |------|
|//1080/|  x  |//680//|  or  | 3x4  |   // = crop
|///////| 400 |///////|      |------|
|///////|     |///////|      |//////|
|///////|_____|///////|      |//////|
```

I have done so far :(

### http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/g25J6/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself, it was hard :D It taked me 2h becouse i never used canvas xD so my final solution is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/g25J6/7/

```
              var w = this.width;
                  h = this.height,
                  cw = canvas.width,
                  ch = canvas.height,
                  nx = 0,
                  ny = 0,
                  r = h/w;
                      if(h<w) {
                         //horizontal image
                             r = w/h;
                             nh = 400,
                             nw = r*400;
                             nx = -(nw-300)/2;

                      } else {
                         //vertical image
                             nw = 300,
                             nh = r*300;
                             ny = -(nh-400)/2;
                      }
```

The image is centered and croped by matching size.
I hope it will help you too.
Bay